# Nginx vod-module with Amazon s3 behind ELB 504

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

Well, a lot of services working together here, but nothing complex really.

I have a ec2 running nginx+[nginx-vod-module](https://github.com/kaltura/nginx-vod-module) and we use a s3 bucket as media source. Accessing the media by going directly to the ec2 instance works fine. After adding an ELB in front of the EC2 I get 504-error.

I think the problem has to do something with a combination `vod_upstream_location` and `X-Forwarded-For header` but I'm not sure.

vod.conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name _;

    access_log off;
    error_log /opt/nginx/logs/vod_error.log;

    open_file_cache          max=1000 inactive=5m;
    open_file_cache_valid    2m;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 1;
    open_file_cache_errors   on;

    vod_upstream_location /s3;
    vod_mode remote;
    vod_metadata_cache metadata_cache 256m;
    vod_response_cache response_cache 256m;

    location /s3/ {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://s3bucket-url.amazonaws.com/;
      }

    location /hls/ {
        vod hls;
        gzip on;
        gzip_types application/x-mpegURL;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    }

    location /hds/ {

        vod hds;
        vod_segment_duration 6000;
        vod_align_segments_to_key_frames on;
        vod_segment_count_policy last_rounded;

        add_header Last-Modified "Sun, 19 Nov 2000 08:52:00 GMT";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        expires 100d;
    }

    location /crossdomain.xml {
        alias /opt/nginx/html/crossdomain.xml;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /status/ {
        vod_status;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things to check: Is the instance listed in the load balancer? If not, check the security groups and make sure the SG on the instance allows access from the SG on the ELB.